# Basic C++ File Handling Problems

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am making a Course Management System. I plan to write a code that takes the input from the user about the details of the university program and store them in the file and read it. My computer firstly does not read the file and secondly does not shows the input option for entering data in school can anyone please resolve the issue.
Thank You

```
void admin() {
system("CLS");
title();
char wish;
ofstream fbout;
ifstream fbin;
fbout.open("program.txt", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);

program degree;
if (!fbout) {
    cerr << "Error in openning file" << endl;
    }
else{
    while (fbin.read((char*)&degree, sizeof(degree))) {
        int i(1);
        cout << i <<". "<< degree.category <<" " <<degree.name <<" (" <<degree.callName << ")" << "\t" <<degree.school<<endl;
    }
    cout << "Enter new program (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> wish;
    if (wish == 'Y') {
        cout << "Program Name : "; cin >> degree.name;
        cout<< flush;
        cout << "School Name : "; cin >> degree.school; cout << endl;
        cout << flush << "Degree Type : "; cin >> degree.category; cout << endl;
        cout << "Acronym : "; cin >> degree.callName;

        fbout.write((char*)&degree, sizeof(degree));
        fbout.close();
        admin();
    }
    else{
    fbout.close();
    admin();}

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22IQE.png)

Comment: Where to you open the input file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You copied some code from somewhere wrong

```
fbout.open("program.txt", ios::out || ios::app||ios::binary);
```

should be

```
fbout.open("program.txt", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
```

`||` is the logical or operator but `|` is the bitwise or operator. Take too long to explain the difference here, look them up in your C++ book. The bitwise or operator is often used to combine several 'flags' into a single value.

Comment: Yeah I fixed that. I just mistyped it from my college slides. Can you please solve the other problem of me unable to enter the data in Degree Type. Thank you

Comment: @SaadAli Like I said above you haven't described what the problem is very well. Please give more details on exactly what is happening when you run your code.

Comment: Firstly John Thank you very much. It was very amateur of me of asking such a silly problem on stack overflow. When I was entering my first data for Program Name I entered "Mechanical Engneering ". and was using cin operater because of which after space Engineering was saved into the other query i,e, School Name and console was not showing the option to enter data in it. I have understood the issue. Thank you for time

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.
I need to open the fbin file using the code statement

```
fbin.open("program.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
```

but I am unable to solve the issue of being unable to enter data in School Name.

Comment: You are going to have to describe what exactly is happening. Does your program crash, does the keyboard stop working, does it not respond to the enter key etc etc. Just saying 'i can;t enter data' is not very helpful.

Comment: Some more problems with your code. You have two file variables `fbin` and `fbout`. Nowhere do you open the `fbin` file but you do try to use it to read, so that is not going to work. You will find that you cannot have two file variables open on the same file at the same time, especially if one is for reading and one is for writing. So write you code so that you are not attempting to read and write simultaneously. When you have finished reading, close the file, similarly when you have finished writing close the file. That way you won't be trying to do both together.

Comment: Another point, all those `cout << flush;` statements are unnecessary. `cout` flushes automatically when you read from `cin`. We say that `cin` is *tied* to `cout`.

Comment: Don't worry about asking basic questions, no question is too basic for SO. It's badly asked questions that annoy people (i.e. question that are hard to answer because they don't give enough information, or questions that show no effort on the part of the asker).